# Why -1 in inputstream represents end of http response

Tags: java, android, http

In Android docs : https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html
We can find this: -1 is the end of inputstream, it means we reach the end fo the http response

> getContentLength() returns the number of bytes transmitted and cannot be used to predict how many bytes can be read from getInputStream() for compressed streams. Instead, read that stream until it is exhausted, i.e. when read() returns -1.

Why the -1 can represents the http response

Comment: _All_ `InputStream`s use that convention.

Answer (score 0):

The -1 is not specific to HTTP-handling, in fact every InputStream will return -1 from read() upon EOF, so you have to deal with it every time you use one.

If you have text here and you want to simplify your code you may be able to wrap your code in a Reader via InputStreamReader and then in a BufferedReader, then you can callreadLine() in a loop until it returns null.